# Excel VBA: Can't set pivotitem "(blank)" position property in Pivot Table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot-table

Excel pivot tables are a headache to code in VBA!

I want a VBA code that loops through each pivot table, then pivot field 
and for each pivot item that is "(blank)" move it either to position 1 or to last position.

Thanks for your help!

```
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables

pt.RefreshTable
pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems

If pi.Caption = "(blank)" Then

pi.position = 1 ' <-- Error 2024, not available? 

If pi.Visible = True Then
pi.Visible = False
End if 

Exit For
End If

Next pi 
Next pf
Next pt
```

Answer (score 2):

In my limited testing this is error-free and works:

```
Sub HideAndMoveTheBlanks()

Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim pf As Excel.PivotField
Dim pi As Excel.PivotItem

For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
    pt.RefreshTable
    pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
        On Error Resume Next
        Set pi = pf.PivotItems("(blank)")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not pi Is Nothing Then
            pi.Position = 1
            pi.Visible = False
            Set pi = Nothing
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pf
Next pt
End Sub
```